Is there a way using serde to define a struct as the result of an "explode"?
I have a serializable struct defined as:
#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Test {
    a: i32,
    b: Vec<i32>,
}

I'd like to store as many records of this struct as there are items in b.
And, if possible, doing so recursively and in a generic way (in my real life example, there are way more fields and deeply nested data).
The thing is, I cannot find a way in serde that creates several records from a single one.
Here is my code:
use serde::Serialize;
use serde_query::Deserialize;

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Test {
    a: i32,
    b: Vec<i32>,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct ExplodedTest {
    #[query("???")]
    a: i32,
    #[query("???")]
    b: i32,
}

fn main() -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    let test_struct = Test {
        a: 5,
        b: vec![1, 2, 3, 4],
    };

    let writer = std::io::BufWriter::new(std::fs::File::create("test.json")?);
    let mut serializer = serde_json::Serializer::new(writer);

    test_struct.serialize(&mut serializer)?;

    Ok(())
}


The idea is to turn struct test (that serializes to {"a":5,"b":[1,2,3]}) into several structs, each one serializing to {"a":5,"b":1}, {"a":5,"b":2}, and {"a":5,"b":3}
I don't know a lot about rust, and using serde_query doesn't seem to help a lot.
I was thinking about implementing my own serializer, but not sure if there is an existing solution. Any advice would be very much appreciated!

I’d just map it after the fact

Frankly speaking, I don't know ready to use a solution too for such a case.
I think writing own Serialize implementation should be relatively simple.
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Test {
    a: i32,
    b: Vec<i32>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Output {
    a: i32,
    b: i32,
}

impl Serialize for Test {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        let mut sequence = serializer.serialize_seq(self.b.len().into())?;

        for item in &self.b {
            sequence.serialize_element(&Output {
                a: self.a,
                b: *item,
            })?;
        }

        sequence.end()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let serialized = serde_json::to_string(&Test {
        a: 4,
        b: vec![1, 2, 3],
    })
    .unwrap();

    println!("Serialized: {}", serialized);
}

Then even Deserialize should not be hard to implement too.
struct Data(Vec<Output>);

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Data {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        deserializer.deserialize_map(DataVisitor)
    }
}

struct DataVisitor;

impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for DataVisitor {
    type Value = Data;

    fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        formatter.write_str("a map containing `a` as an integer and `b` as an array of integers")
    }

    fn visit_map<M>(self, mut map: M) -> Result<Self::Value, M::Error>
    where
        M: MapAccess<'de>,
    {
        let mut a = None;
        let mut b = None;

        while let Some(key) = map.next_key::<String>()? {
            match key.as_str() {
                "a" => {
                    if a.is_some() {
                        return Err(de::Error::duplicate_field("a"));
                    }
                    a = Some(map.next_value()?);
                }
                "b" => {
                    if b.is_some() {
                        return Err(de::Error::duplicate_field("b"));
                    }
                    b = Some(map.next_value()?);
                }
                _ => {
                    return Err(de::Error::unknown_field(&key, &["a", "b"]));
                }
            }
        }

        let a = a.ok_or_else(|| de::Error::missing_field("a"))?;
        let b: Vec<i32> = b.ok_or_else(|| de::Error::missing_field("b"))?;

        Ok(Data(
            b.into_iter().map(|item| Output { a, b: item }).collect(),
        ))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let json_data = r#"{"a":5,"b":[1,2,3]}"#;

    let outputs: Data = serde_json::from_str(json_data).unwrap();

    for output in outputs.0 {
        println!("{:?}", output);
    }
}

You could also add templates for the serialization process.
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Output<T: Clone> {
    a: T,
    b: T,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Test<T: Clone> {
    a: T,
    b: Vec<T>,
}

impl<T> Serialize for Test<T>
where
    T: Clone + Serialize,
{
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        let mut sequence = serializer.serialize_seq(self.b.len().into())?;

        for item in &self.b {
            sequence.serialize_element(&Output {
                a: self.a.clone(),
                b: item.clone(),
            })?;
        }

        sequence.end()
    }
}

Also, cloning could be avoided, but it's just more fine-tuning that could be implemented in the future.

Thanks a lot!
I get the idea. I was thinking of defining my own Serializer but your answer makes me realize a custom Serialize implementation would be more relevant.
